# Eclipse can't find my MinGW toolchain for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, mingw, toolchain

I have a problem. Many have the same question but I didn't find the answer.

I installed gcc-4.9.0 on my PC but Eclipse won't find it.
I used the default installation path:

```
C:\MinGW
```

Comment: Look in the preferences/settings of your Eclipse, there's probably an option somewhere to specify the path.

Answer (score 5):

1. Setting PATH variable, add something like: "C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1\mingw32\bin"
2. DO **COPY** gcc.exe to mingw32-gcc.exe in your path above

For more information, see:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#I_installed_MinGW_toolchain_on_my_PC_but_Eclipse_won.27t_find_it.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem recently.  I had some difficulty getting my Eclipse Luna SR2 4.4.2 running on Win 7 SP1 to see my newly-installed MinGW-w64 but I was able to resolve it by adding a MINGW_HOME environmental variable to my Win 7 installation, and then restarting Eclipse.  (I didn't need to restart Windows.)

In my case, MinGW-w64 had installed itself at "C:Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-4.9.2-win32-seh-rt_v4_rev2" and so I needed to set MINGW_HOME to "C:Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-4.9.2-win32-seh-rt_v4_rev2\mingw64" so that it would point to the appropriate subdirectories (bin, etc, include, lib, ...).

In Win 7, environmental variables can be set via the "Environment Variables" button on the Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings.  I added my MINGW_HOME variable to the "User variables" section.

Answer (score 2):

This steps helped me when I faced the same problem:

First add the MinGW directory to your path system environment variable as in this link:

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLpaYVIoXqc)

After this when you want to create a project uncheck "Show project types and toolchains only if they are supported on the platorm" option. Choose MinGW GCC

Create your code but first build it with CTRL+B, after this mine worked perfectly.

I wish it will be helpful for other people who see this

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse uses the system environment variable "PATH" to find a toolchain. So, in order to Eclipse could find MinGW toolchain, the path the to bin-directory of MinGW (e.g. "C:\MinGW\bin") should be specified in the "PATH" environment variable.

P.S. And don't forget to re-launch Eclipse after modifying the environment variable :)

Answer (score 1):

OPEN ECLIPSE **>** WINDOW ([view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quVek.png))  **>** BUILD **>** ENVIRONMENT ([view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBab3.png))  >
and click the **Select** button you can see your **variable** list and **Select the PATH variable** and press **ok** button. ([view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxVXr.png)) >
after this done you can **edit the value of PATH** put your path of mingw eg:'C:\mingw64\bin' after the semi colon';' and apply and close then restart the eclipse its done.([view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MHuV.png))

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a while and just now got it to work.
Here's what I did:
In Eclipse, go to Window>Preferences>C/C++>Build>Environment. Double click the row that has PATH in the leftmost column to open the list. **Make sure** you've got \bin at the end of your C:\MinGW in that list. Mine didn't have the \bin. I changed it to read C:\MinGW\bin and now it works like a charm.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the above steps one thing I missed to do was saving user settings after adding the path variable. This suggested that the path for MinGW was not saved correctly.

Please check-in that aspect as well.

Comment: I went through all steps.  If path variable is not set in right way this issue will occur

Comment: @richardec This doesn't look like a "thanks" to me.

Comment: Recommended to delete this answer by accident.

Answer (score 0):

A mismatch of 32 and 64 bit versions of eclipse and mingw can also contribute the gcc/g++ not-found problem. Make sure you stick to one version all the way from java, mingw, to eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

After updating the environment path variable, you must restart os.